# High fan speed all the time on the Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop Asus n552-vw, but the problem is that, when I install Ubuntu(even through installation) my fan speed goes up and remains there at the highest level!
I tried many other distro's like Debian, fedora, open suse, etc, also windows 10, but the problem is only on Ubuntu!

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Ok, I entirely changed my question and wrote a problem that I had when I tested Ubuntu at first and after unsuccessful try changed to Debian!

Comment: The fan speed may increase to compensate for heated CPU due to a process running at full CPU %. There can be many reasons. Next time, access terminal, and use `top -o %CPU` to identify the process(es) that may be using too much processor time. Also consider looking at logs in /var/log for diagnostic messages. If a process is sending many messages to logs, you may be able to narrow down the logs to check by typing `ls -lt /var/log | head`